# sequence issue php glob

Tags: php

i want to display files one after another sequentially in a web page so i have used glob in php.
i want my files to be displayed in the following manner:

```
video1
video2
video3
  .
  .
  .
video9
video10
video11
```

but i am getting output as:

```
video1
video10
video11
video2
video3
 .......
```

Follwing is the exact logic i wrote:

```
if ($_GET['name'])
{
        $query = $_GET['name'];
}else{
        $query = "NULL";
}

foreach(glob('video/*'.$query.'*.mp4') as $filename)
{
        $filename = substr($filename, 6);
        echo "<a href=".$server_path."".$filename.">".$filename."</a><br>";
}
```

please help me out guyss...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the natural order sorting function [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) as:

```
$arr = glob('video/*'.$query.'*.mp4');
natsort($arr);
foreach($arr as $filename) {
```

Comment: @user1372331: Good to know. Don't forge to mark the answer that helped you the most as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It won't solve the immediate problem, but at least now you know why people name their files as: video0001 and so on.

There is a sorting function for this kind of cases.